# What's the best way to parallelize this process

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I've been trying parallelize a process inside a class method. When I try using `Pool()` from `multiprocessing` I get pickling errors. When I use `Pool()` from `multiprocessing.dummy` my execution is slower than serialized execution.

I've attempted several variations of my code below, using Stackoverflow posts as a guide, but none of them were a successful workaround for the problem outlined above.

One for example: if I move `process_function` above the class definition (globalizing it) it's doesn't work because I can't access my objects attributes.

Anyway, my code is similar to:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
from my_other_module import other_module_class   

class myClass:

    def __init__(self, some_list, number_iterations):

        self.my_interface = other_module_class
        self.relevant_list = []
        self.some_list = some_list
        self.number_iterations = number_iterations
        # self.other_attributes = stuff from import statements

    def load_relevant_data:

        self.relevant_list = self.interface.other_function

    def compute_foo(self, relevant_list_member_value):

        # math involving class attributes

        return foo_scalar

    def higher_function(self):

        self.relevant_list = self.load_relevant_data
        np.random.seed(0)
        pool = ThreadPool() # I've tried different args here, no help
        pool.map(self.process_function, self.relevant_list)

    def process_function(self, dict_from_relevant_list):

        foo_bar = self.compute_foo(dict_from_relevant_list['key'])
        a = 0
        for i in some_other_list:

            # do other stuff involving class attributes and foo_bar
            # a = some of that

        dict_from_relevant_list['other_key'] = a


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import time
    import pprint as pp

    some_list = blah
    number_of_iterations = 10**4
    my_obj = myClass(some_list, number_of_iterations
    my_obj.load_third_parties()
    start = time.time()
    my_obj.higher_function()
    execution_time = time.time() - start
    print()
    print("Execution time for %s simulation runs: %s" % (number_of_iterations, execution_time))
    print()
    pp.pprint(my_obj.relevant_list[0:5])
```

I have a few hundred dictionaries inside relevant list. I just want to populate each of those dictionary's `'other_key'` field from a computationally expensive simulation on my inner most loop, which yields a scalar value, like `a` above. It seems like there should be a simple way to do this since in Matlab I could just right `parfor` and it's done automatically. Maybe that instinct is wrong for Python.

Comment: you can globalize your function and then include a parameter to pass your object in...`def process_function(dict_from_relevant_list, object)` then call it with `process_function(dictionary_stuff, self)` which will pass the object to your function allowing it to access its methods and variables via `object.variable`

Comment: If your processing code is purely numerical, I recommend parallelizing your loop with [`numba`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/parallel.html).